# How to prevent reading app.config?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports, app-config

Sorry if this looks like a stupid question.

My application uses a connection string to connect to a SQL Server 2008 database and uses Crystal Report, my server use mix authentication mode.

The problem is: `app.config` file shows connection string (user name & password) which I don't want anyone to see!

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ComplainsDb;Persist Security Info=false; User ID=abcde ;Password=MyPassword
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Encrypt the app.config. Google it you will find lots of about it ..

Comment: Related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637348/encrypt-connection-string-in-app-config)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call something like this when your program starts:

```
    void EncryptConnectionStringsIfNecessary()
    {
        var configFile = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        ConnectionStringsSection section = configFile.ConnectionStrings;
        if (section != null)
        {
            if (!section.IsReadOnly())
            {
                if (!section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
                {
                    section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("DataProtectionConfigurationProvider");
                    section.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
                    configFile.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That is work for me so far.. but how can i decrypt this file??

Comment: You don't usually need to do anything. As explained in [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh8x3tas.aspx),  the .NET framework will decrypt the settings automatically when you access `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionStringName]`.

Comment: FYI: `ConfigFile` should be `configFile`. ;)

Comment: Thanks @JamesWilkins. Updated.