# Saving private key in application

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, configuration, rsa

I want to create custom configuration for my application, not using the app.config.

So for example I want to make some ini file that stores the configuration itself and want to make it encrypted. So I want to encrypt connection string, passwords, etc that will be in this file.

I want to use RSACryptoServiceProvider. So i will create config file with a public key, and my application will decrypt those with private key. I need to store this private key inside the application somehow.

I can put is as const string value, but it's easy to see it when you reverse engineer the application.

So, what is the best way to store the private key inside my application?

How RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider does it?

Comment: The best way would be to encrypt it, but then you need to store the key for that somehow...

Comment: encypt the private key with other encryption and store as string?

Comment: The dilemma is that you are only adding a layer of complexity, not security, as there is a key in plain text in the end. The point is that the best way to protect the key doesn't pan out as it leaves you with the same problem as you start with. You have to make do with something that is second best, like obstruction.

Comment: How then RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider does it under the hood?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encrypt connection string in app.config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637348/encrypt-connection-string-in-app-config)

Comment: it's different question, cause I'm saying about separate custom configuration

Comment: @anderhil: It uses an encryption key protected by the system at a user level. It's stored in the computer, not the application, so you need to encrypt the data on the same computer that is going to read it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Data Protection API, which is intended for this kind of use. It stores per-user secrets in Windows.

The key won't be as easy to retrieve, but bear in mind that this solution relies on Windows Security. The user for which you have stored the key will be able to retrieve it again easily (but other users cannot).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Protection_API

To use it from .NET, start with the documentation for the [ProtectedData Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.aspx).

Comment: But I need to have private key per application, cause it will be distibuted to lots of other computers.

Comment: It's the never-ending problem with cryptography, you need to store the keys somewhere you can retrieve them. Can you issue each user a different key, in use that key to ultimately decrypt the master key. Or redesign so individual clients don't need the master key. Ultimately, there is no *safe and 'good'* way to store the key, other than deriving it from something the user inputs, such as the password. The Windows DPAPI solution does this since it indirectly relies on the Windows user's password.

Comment: Yes I understand that, that's why I asked what is the best solution? I'd say even just acceptable solution, I want to be protected at least from simple reverse engineering - when you can read the strings that are stored as consts. So private key should be distributed with/in the application.