# Connection string really needed in XML?

Tags: xml, vb.net, string, connection, config

Im programming a VB.net application that automatically created a xml file that conntains a connection string to a SQL server(user & pw).. Is it really neccessary to have that line in the XML?? I erased it and it seems to be working fine..Just want to get rid of it for security purposes.

Comment: ok... you deleted your connection string. How is your application connecting to your db now?

Comment: the connection string is contained within the source...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's useful to put your connection string in some kind of config file (xml or ini or whatever) in case you move your database to another server or you change your login credentials and so on...

if you think you'll never need this and prefer to rebuild and redeploy your application, then no, you don't need any xml configuration file with the connection string in it.

If you're worried about security you could keep it in the xml file encrypted and then decrypt it runtime.

[Connection Strings and Configuration Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[Encrypt connection string in app.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637348/encrypt-connection-string-in-app-config)

Comment: Thanks! Im looking into that.