# Best practice for connecting to entity SQL DB on Azure from ASP.NET API

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, azure

I am currently connecting to a SQL db deployed to azure via a connection string in the constructor of my DBContext class, like so :

```
public class ImageContext : DbContext
{
    public ImageContext() : base("Data Source=tcp:example.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=example;User Id=exampleacc@example.database.windows.net;Password=example")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<item1> item1 { get; set; }
    public DbSet<item2> item2 { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
```

I recognize this as a bad practice because I have my username and password as plain text in the source code. Can someone please point me in the right direction to connect to this DB safely?

Comment: There are several best practices but if you want something simple you can put the connection string in a config file.  If you want it to be encrypted you can use the following website for info: https://www.codeproject.com/tips/598863/encryptionplusdecryptionplusconnectionplusstringpl

Comment: Store the connection string in the web.config and encrypt it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637348/encrypt-connection-string-in-app-config

Comment: Another idea would be to use Azure KeyVault to store the username, password, and/or connection string.

Comment: Is there any benefit to putting the string into the web.config file without encrypting it? Also a quick idea of how to implement that would be awesome. I've tried before but could not get it to work..