# How to connect to MySQL database from vb.net using app.config

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I need help in how to convert my current connection and migrate in using `app.config` in my vb.net project so when I transfer or edit my database credentials I don't need to recompile new installer for my program. Thanks in advance mates!

Here is my current connection:

(code inside my `mdlConnection.vb`)

```
Module mdlConnection
    Public connString1 As String = "server=localhost;user id=root;password=;Database=sampleprog"
    Public conn As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(connString1)
    Public sql As String = ""

    Public Function ExecuteQuery(ByVal query As String) As DataTable
        Dim sqlDT As New DataTable
        Try
            Dim sqlCon As New MySqlConnection(connString1)
            Dim sqlDA As New MySqlDataAdapter(query, sqlCon)
            Dim sqlCB As New MySqlCommandBuilder(sqlDA)
            sqlDA.Fill(sqlDT)
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
        Return sqlDT
    End Function
End Module
```

This is the config inside my `app.config`:

[image]

Comment: You can add a connection string on the Settings page of the project properties. That will be automatically added to the config file and you can access it in code via `My.Settings`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I opened this question and started typing an answer a then got distracted. I just noticed now that I have submitted it that you had a similar suggestion in your comment. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Fabulous Sir I just followed your instructions and edited my codes and i encountered some errors btw thanks you

Comment: Thank youu too mr @jmcilhinney

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: @Fabulous there is no more errors I just forgot to add the system config reference it now fully functional thanks again and btw is there a way that I can easily encrypt the database password if i put one so no one can see it thru my app.config if ever someone tries to sneak in my project.

Comment: Hi @DDD, for that I would recommend you [look at this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637348/encrypt-connection-string-in-app-config)

Comment: Thank you very much for all the help guys! ♥

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your current app.config file as below :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
        <startup> 
            <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
        </startup>

        <connectionStrings>
            <add name="MySqlConnectionString" connectionString="SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=sampleprog;UID=root;PASSWORD=;" />
        </connectionStrings>

    </configuration>
```

And then modify your 'mdlConnection.vb' code as below :

```
    Module mdlConnection
        Public connString1 As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MySqlConnectionString").ToString()
        Public conn As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(connString1)
        Public sql As String = ""

        Public Function ExecuteQuery(ByVal query As String) As DataTable
            Dim sqlDT As New DataTable
            Try
                Dim sqlCon As New MySqlConnection(connString1)
                Dim sqlDA As New MySqlDataAdapter(query, sqlCon)
                Dim sqlCB As New MySqlCommandBuilder(sqlDA)
                sqlDA.Fill(sqlDT)
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
            Return sqlDT
        End Function
    End Module
```

Please don't forget the add the namespace 'Imports System.Configuration' in your 'mdlConnection.vb' and the reference 'System.Configuration' in your solution.

Comment: @DDD - Did my answer help you?

Comment: Yes sir thank you very much your answer is exactly what my project needed. Im just having some struggle in trying to encrypt my database password

Comment: @DDD - You can find some useful information on [Encrypting and Decrypting your DB config section here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Sir I have a follow up question for this. What will I change if I will use a local server stand alone pc  in my LAN as my wampserver / mysqlserver  Im using its ip 192.168.1.2. @M.d Suman Kabir

Answer (score 0):

Double click on your project's "My Project" entry in solution explorer. Go to the settings tab from the window that opens. Change the type to Connection String as shown in the screenshot below

[image: Settings page, setting type to Connection String.]

Alternatively, you can add the following to your app.config file below the `<configuration>` opening tag;

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="<Desired name here>" connectionString="server=localhost;user id=root;password=;Database=sampleprog" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup>
    ...
</configuration>
```

You can then access the connection string as follows in your code.

```
Dim con = My.Settings.DbConnection ' provided you named your connection string DbConnection in the first step above.
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is my settings**

[image]

**here is my updated mdlConnection**

[image]

**here is my updated mdlConnection**

```
Dim con = My.Settings.DbConnection
Public conn As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(con)
Public sql As String = ""

Public Function ExecuteQuery(ByVal query As String) As DataTable
    Dim sqlDT As New DataTable
    Try
        Dim sqlCon As New MySqlConnection(con)
        Dim sqlDA As New MySqlDataAdapter(query, sqlCon)
        Dim sqlCB As New MySqlCommandBuilder(sqlDA)
        sqlDA.Fill(sqlDT)
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    Return sqlDT
End Function
```

Comment: Please don't use images. If possible use plain text inside an answer.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I will take it note the next time I post my questions thankyouuu!