# Non-clear-text way to specify password for different environment.

Tags: secret-key, shared-secret

I have test dll which needs connection string to DB. I need a way to store/specify non clear text way to specify connection string for various environments. I have a way of doing this in clear text way using Slow Cheetah transformation but I need a way where the passwords are not clear text.

My issue is super common and I am surprised to see no solution/recommendation.

Please advice.

Comment: On mobile atm or would explain more, but a google for “encrypt web.config” should help.

Comment: @DavidSpense, I am not using IIS hosting. My DLL is super basic.

Comment: You don't have to be using IIS. The same applies for a console application and app.config. Potentially helpful: 1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29177724/609176 2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files