# about VB.net & MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, passwords

IF I write code below in my program

```
Dim conn As New SqlConnection With {.ConnectionString = "Server= serverIP ; Database=datafile ;User= username ;Pwd= password ;"}
```

If I use debug or other file viewer, is not easy to find security data like password ?

How to avoid security data lose?

Comment: Yes it is easy. That's what Windows Authentication is for, it doesn't use passwords

Comment: Take a read of this question: [Encrypt connection string in app.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637348/encrypt-connection-string-in-app-config)

Comment: similar in Android APP code below

            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            ConnectionURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + server + ";"
                    + "databaseName=" + database + ";user=" + user
                    + ";password=" + password + ";";
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionURL);

is easy to find password too.
How can I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I use "File Viewer Plus 3" to view .exe file inspect then search. cannot find security data like server IP, user, password.
I feel VB.net has hide it.

Comment: similar Android APP is too.